# New Project configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have installed ruby and rails on my system properly, create new project then its shows some error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.9)

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find minitest-4.7.5.gem for installation
An error occurred while installing minitest (4.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install minitest -v '4.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am stuck here... please help me....

Comment: Ca you show your Gemfile. I added gem 'minitest' to mine and it was successfully installed. I noticed that I was not able to access repos on Github since last hour or so. May be thats why the gem not found error occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to remove this error just do this

```
gem install minitest -v '4.7.5'
```

after you do

```
$ rails new abc
```

may be you face this jQuery error so run this command also
    $ sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: this error you face when gem is not proper install to do this install gem and after that run this command  sudo apt-get install nodejs to run the server.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are stucked here. In terminal just copy and paste it

```
gem install minitest -v '4.7.5'
```

This command will install `minitest` gem and then you can run the bundle command again to install remaining gems.

Comment: Yes I have installed it already but it was giving the same error again but i have resolved it because there was problem of json so that i have to installed first. But thanks Ishank Gupta for your immediate response.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command after entering into your project folder

```
bundle install
```

Comment: If there is a problem with installing `minitest` gem, then continuously rerunning `bundle install` may not help. It could be better to ensure that `minitest` gem is installed successfully and then rerun `bundle install`.